# Not understanding MySQL SUM() output

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fundamentally understand why my code is producing these results:
I have two tables

```
R(A, B): {(0,1), (2,3), (0,1), (2,2), (3, 2)}
```

and

```
S(B, C):{(0,1), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (0,2)}
```

I'm supposed to find the results of the relational algebra: Gamma (A, sum(B))(R)
As far as I understand it this is supposed to be the answer: **{(0, 2), (2, 5), (3, 2)}**
And my code I wrote was:

**select  sum(B), A
from R
group by A;**

When I just simply sum(B) with:

**select sum(B)
from R;**

I get the sum being 9. I understand SUM() to be summing everything in column B but when I use the code I wrote before that I don't understand what values are being summed in the 2nd column and why the answer is this {(0, 2), (2, 5), (3, 2)} (as I mentioned above). Any help understanding how and what numbers are being added to produce these results would greatly help. Thank you!

Comment: You never wrote what the unexpected result you got is. But the expected result you did post is incorrect: your output tuple is the sum first followed by the group key, so all your expectations are flipped, it should be `{(2, 0), (5, 2), (2, 3)}`.  [Trying it out on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/986e6c/1/0) that's exactly what I get. Furthermore because you don't *order* the query, they might be in any order in the resultset as it depends how the table data is laid out, and how mysql decides to execute the grouping (in fiddle, mysql and sqlite did order per A but postgres did not)

Answer (score 0):

I tested on MySQL 8.0:

```
create table R ( A int, B int); 
insert into T values (0,1), (2,3), (0,1), (2,2), (3, 2);

select sum(B), A from R group by A;
+--------+------+
| sum(B) | A    |
+--------+------+
|      2 |    0 |
|      5 |    2 |
|      2 |    3 |
+--------+------+

select sum(B) from R;
+--------+
| sum(B) |
+--------+
|      9 |
+--------+
```

When grouping by A, the SUM(B) reports the sum for each group of rows.

When not grouping, the whole set of rows counts as one group, so the SUM(B) should be the sum for all the rows.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html says:

> If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

2 + 5 + 2 = 9, right?